# Why do C languages require parens around a simple condition in an if statement?

Tags: c#, java, javascript, c++, c

It sounds stupid, but over the years I haven't been able to come up with a use case that would require this. A quick google search didn't reveal anything worthwhile.

From memory there was a use case mentioned by Bjarne Stroustrup but i can't find a reference to it.

So why can't you have this in C languages:

```
int val = 0;
if val
  doSomehing();
else
  doSomehinglse();
```

I can accept the "we couldn't be bothered adding support to lexer" reason, I just want to figure out if this syntax breaks other language constructs. Considering how many whacky syntax features there are in C/C++, i hardly think this would have added much complexity.

Comment: Because that is how the language is defined?

Comment: I think it can become a problem with a bunch of nested if / else blocks.

Comment: Good question. And cx0der: *Why* is it defined like that? Many languages allow you to omit the parentheses. Is there a case in the C family of languages where it'd actually introduce ambiguity into the parser? I can't think of any.

Comment: Whoever removed javascript tag - `if val` is invalid in javascript too.

Comment: @jalf compiled languages don't allow that. I have come across only interpreted languages that allow you to do that.

Comment: @cx0der: Many compiled languages do allow it. Interpreted vs compiled has **nothing** to do with it. The problem is the syntax of the language, not the way the code is executed *after* it has been parsed

Comment: I think you mean parenthesis, not brackets?

Comment: @cx0der Being compiled is no excuse to not allow something like that. if (x) and if x could easily be compiled to the same thing.

Comment: As an expression is a statement. You need some way to mark the end of the condition expression and the first statement inside the if block (which could be another expression). There are several possable solutions one of which is to use () around the condidition.

Comment: use colon as a marker for the end of the condition on single statement. just use the open curly bracket as end of condition marker for multiple statements

Comment: Some other languages use 'then' to mark the end of the condition; the keywords act like parentheses.  Dennis Ritchie chose not to use a keyword to separate the condition from the action, choosing instead to use parentheses.  Some languages have keywords to introduce all statements; such languages do not need the parentheses because again, the keywords mark the start of the next statement so the separation of condition and action is unambiguous.

Comment: I vaguely remember using a C compiler in the late 90s that had a non-standard extension - you could use `if !(x && y)` as shorthand for `if (!(x && y))`, and that did not create syntactic ambiguities.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If there are no brackets around expressions in `if` constructs, what would be the meaning of the following statement?

```
if x * x * b = NULL;
```

Is it

```
if (x*x)
    (*b) = NULL;
```

or is it

```
if (x)
    (*x) * b = NULL;
```

(of course these are silly examples and don't even work for obvious reasons but you get the point)

**TLDR: Brackets are required in C to remove even the possibility of any syntactic ambiguity.**

Comment: … or `if ( x * x * b = NULL ) ;` will look fine to the parser until it tries to match functions to the operations.

Comment: This really isn't a good answer to the question. C strictly dictates the order of operations for operators. If that were valid syntax it would be evaluated as if(NULL) because * takes precedence over = and the return value of an assignment is the value assigned, and there is no logical reason why a compiler which didn't require brackets around a conditional would split the statement after the if (look at python syntax).

Comment: Chris: The point is, the LR parser needs to be able to decide where the condition ends and where the conditional block begins. Different languages have different approaches, some require brackets, some newlines and some have the "then" keyword. You just can't get around that. Show me _one_ language that doesn't have some mechanism for separating the conditional expression from the conditional block some way or other. If you still don't believe me, try to build your own language syntax with yacc and you will see all the issues that will come up.

Comment: @Chris: even if there is an unambigious way to parse this, it would be much less obvious, and difficult to read, hence a bad idea. For example, I always put in extra parens with nested and/or/not conditions, even if they are not necessary. Saves everyone time thinking about how the implicit priorities would work out.

Comment: This kinds sounds to me like allowing this will need to make `if` statement almost like an operator with its own precedence rules.

Comment: @Chris: so you just arbitrarily decided to use a greedy algorithm and use the longest possible expression. That will end badly (pun intended). Python delimits the condition by the newline. Languages that don't require parens, like ML, don't alias symbols between unary and binary operators.

Comment: If someone adds a generalisation to this post, something like "In order to disambiguate condition from statement" for fatheads like myself I will accept it as an answer ;)

Comment: Thanks for hte bold. I**definitely** get it now ;)

Comment: can't you solve this by disallowing eliding braces? e.g. `if( foo ) bar;` becomes `if foo { bar; }`.

Comment: C has an ambiguous grammar, parentheses in conditionals or not. Consider: `a * b;` What does it mean? A simple multiplication that throws away the result, or a declaration of a pointer? The grammar is ambiguous and the compiler needs context to resolve it. I think the answer to this question is "because that's the way it is, that's how Dennis Ritchie liked it".

Comment: That same argumenmt can be applyed to a+b*c or any other chain operation. a+b*c is that (a+b)*c or a+(b*c) I know what the precedence rules says but they work equally on the given example. I'm sry but your answer is incorrect

Comment: @Rune FS: This is isn't about operator precedence, it's about semantics. Read all the comments here for more details.

Comment: @DrJokepu I agree this post is about semantics and that's exactly my point. I don't believe the reason for the if() is semantics. C/C++ is extremely vague when it comes to semantics. Take a statement like this A=B=C it's absolutely impossible to state beyond any doubt what the result is. There's nothing that guarantees that A == C is true, you can't even count on A or B actually being assign. So it would seem very weird at one place to use semantics as the arguement and basically ignore it in the rest of the language.

Answer (score 13):

Tell me how to interprit the following:

```
if x ++ b;
```

Looks silly but...

```
if( x ) ++b;
```

or

```
if( x++ ) b;
```

or perhaps "x" has an overloaded operator then...

```
if( x ++ b){;}
```

Edit:

As Martin York noted "++" has a higher precedence which is why I've had to add the operator overloading tidbit.  He's absolutely right when dealing with modern compilers up until you allow for all that overloading goodness which comes with C++.

Comment: Post increment has a higher priority. So the last one. A better one is if x + b; Is this if (x+b) {;} or if (x) {+b;}

Comment: or a more commonly recognizable one would be `if x - b`, since the unary minus is more familiar to most than unary plus.

Comment: "interprit" has two 'e's in it.

Answer (score 5):

I think a better question would be "why would we want such a thing?" than "why don't we have it?". It introduces another otherwise unnecessary edge case into the lexer, just so you can avoid typing 4 extra characters; and adds complexity to the spec by allowing exceptions to a simple syntax that already supports all possible cases just fine. Not to mention toes the line of ambiguity, which in a programming language doesn't have much value.

Comment: A lot of languages allow you to omit the parentheses and reducing noise always aids clarity. Pretending that it's some kind of insurmountable obstacle is a bit silly. The last part is more interesting. can you *think* of any cases where it'd introduce ambiguity? Otherwise your answer seems to be nothing more than "parentheses were always good enough for ME! Don't come here and suggest that my language isn't perfect"

Comment: Of course it adds complexity. The compiler has to figure out whether the programmer gave it a simple condition (i.e. a bool) or something more complicated; for example, what if the user has a statement 'if someObj doStuff()' where someObj has a huge function for implicit conversion to bool?

Comment: I agree that C++ isn't the right language to be introducing such a feature.  That said, I also think that we are underusing our natural "language instinct" in much of the code we write.  Case in point: the previous sentence has only two quote marks and one comma for punctuation...but we both parse it the same in our heads.  My suspicion is that there are many contexts where programming could leverage the latent shared understanding which allows us to do that.  Lately I've been looking into exactly that question, it's been thought-provoking.

Comment: @dauphic: If you've ever written a parser, you'd know that it only introduces complexity if it creates any ambiguities where none existed previously. For this answer to be meaningful, it'd have to show such an ambiguity. If someObj can be implicitly converted to bool, then the compiler will do that, just as if there'd been ()'s around it. As long as that is the only way the code can be parsed, it'd add zero complexity.

Comment: @Hostile Fork. Unncessary boiler-plate is bad, but too much expressive flexibility can also be bad, even if it does not introduce ambiguity. You are writing code here, not poems. There is no need to make the compiler unreasonably complex (that could easily lead to bugs), and you have to think about the maintenance programmers as well. With a language of more flexibility (such as Perl), you can easily create write-only code, that becomes hard to figure out.

Comment: @Thilo: If your coding isn't an art form on par with poetry, perhaps your sights are set too low. :)  I'll compare with handwriting recognition: at the extremes are full OCR vs. entering your letters in binary ASCII.  A compromise is something like Palm's Graffiti, which introduced exaggerated letterforms that people learned quickly and that computers could recognize without error.  In my view programming languages tend to the extremes instead of asking both human and compiler to meet in the middle at a "sweet spot" of minimum complexity.  Perl is not my ideal in this respect (can't stand it).

Comment: @jalf - "... reducing noise always aids clarity ..." is patently untrue. As a simple counter-example, why do you think some folks add parentheses that are strictly unnecessary?  Because **for some people** the redundant parentheses aid clarity!!

Comment: @Jaff, do you want C to have Python's `pass` statement?

Answer (score 1):

One other possible thing to keep in mind: C was created at a time when tape storage was common, so random seek or going backwards through the current file or even other files was not really feasible (which also explains why you have to put some stuff (i.e. forward declarations) before other stuff (i.e. usage of functions) even though the compiler should be able to figure it out on it's own).

Comment: Tape has nothing to do with it. The emphasis in compiler design has always been on left-to-right processing in linear time. Plenty of other languages have forward-declaration rules, not just the tape-era languages.

Answer (score 0):

i would love that syntax too, but to avoid parsing ambiguties, must be of this form:

for multiple statements:

```
if val 
{ 
    doSomething();
    doOthers();
}
```

for one statement:

```
if val: 
   doSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simply a means of ending the condition clause of the statement.
Other languages use other means such as a "then" or in Python "if condition **:(Followed by a return)**"
(The : always get me in python I keep leaving them out and get errors than aren't immediately obvious as a result.)

Computer grammars typically like some unique mechanizism to identify the different parts of a statement or expression.  It's no better or worst in this respect than any other language.  The dangle else issue with C/C++ is an example of ambiguity from a gramatic standpoint and has to be handled as a special case to insure correct operation.  (i.e. It adds extra work for the compiler implementor.)

Answer (score 0):

unless you want significant white space you need to be able to tell when the condition ends
in some languages it's () around the condition in some it's the keyword then an if like the one given in the answer

if x * x * b = NULL could be one condition always evaluating to false, one assigning null to *b in the case of (x*x) the compiler has no way of knowing when the condition ends and the following operation begins. So there needs to be an explicit "back marker" for the compiler to know when the condition ends. In C(++), Java, c# and other languages it's () marking the condition in F# it's the keyword 'then' and in still other languages it's a newline/indentation

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental reason is that C and friends don't have a 'then' keyword so they need another way to delimit the condition-expression. Languages that do, like Pascal and PL/1, don't need the parentheses. Same applies to 'while', where Pascal, PL/1, etc have a 'do'.

Comment: Actually, if the compiler could now where one expression ends and the next one starts, this would be enough. (But as shown by DrJopeku's answer, it isn't.)

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann Of course it would be enough, and that's what the 'then' keyword provides. Absent a 'then' keyword you run into possible assignment statements and an arbitrary amount of lookahead is required. From the grammar point of view C's '(' is redundant, and ')' is functionally identical to 'then'.

Answer (score 0):

It is because it helps programmer to make compiler understand in which sequence an  expressions( including a sequence of types of operators like arithmetic,logical,assignment,etc) need to be solved in order to get desired output.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>I think you are confusing "brackets" with "parenthesis"</strike>

This is possible in  C:

```
void doSomething(){}
void doSomethingElse(){}

void main() {
    int val = 0;
    if( val ) 
        doSomething();
    else
        doSomethingElse();
}
```

Not all "C" languages force the parethesis usage and and leave braces as optional.   Go ( Issue) programming language does exactly the [opposite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712172/whats-your-take-on-the-programming-language-go/1716703#1716703).

The correct way to write that same sentence in Issue9 would be:

```
if val {
    doSomething();
} else {
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

That way the following is not valid:

```
if x * x * b = NULL;
```

It should be one of:

```
if x*x {
    *b=NULL;
}
```

or
   if x {
       *x*b=NULL;
   }

Here the braces remove the ambiguity created by the lack of parenthesis.

Comment: Great, this just reaffirms the notion that it's either braces or the parentheses.

Comment: ....Or as in Python ( I know it is not from the "C" family but ) using the colon to separate the sentence. It could be: `if x * x : b = None`

Answer (score -1):

I can give at least one example why in C there are paranthesis around conditions,

For example consider the following

```
while(1) do_something();
```

The above will call do_something() for ever in an infinite loop

The reason the parenthis are required is because the following would be ambiguous

`while 1 ; do_something();` 
does that mean, evaluate do_something and do nothing in the while loop? or does it mean the same as the code sample above?

I guess that showes one way why in the C syntax parenthis are required around condition evaluations, and by extending the same syntax (for the sake of consitency) it is extended to the if statements.

Discalaimer: I could be completely wrong and the reason behind having the pranthesis could be completely different, but at least I've shown one example of how it can be useful

Comment: What about "while 1 do_something();"? Removing the parenthesis removes the ability to express an infinite loop by omitting the condition, but it doesn't remove the ability to express an infinite loop.

Comment: Actually I think that needs to be while(1) do_something(). For me using gcc 4.0.1 I get _syntax error before ‘)’ token_ for your code.

Comment: thats true, but your syntactic rules should not allow ambiguos situations like I showed above, so either enforce () around condition statements or enforce {} around while/for/if/else body. C chose to do the first, or go the python route (ie: white space is important). From the outset C doesn't care about whitespaces so they had a choice between mandatory() or mandatory{} they chose the first.

Comment: Adding the 1 has kinda made your example redundant, has it not? I can't see any ambiguity anymore.

Comment: You could just do: while do_something() || 1;

Answer (score -2):

I can't think of any specific cases where omitting the parens would actually cause any ambiguity, but there is probably a corner case somewhere.

It might be related to locally declared variables (as in `if (bool b = foo())...` where without the parentheses, it'd be harder to determine if `bool` is a type declaration or the the entire condition. In the latter case, `b` would then be the first token of the if-statements body, rather than part of the condition.

Comment: Except that allowing a variable definition as part of an expression was not part of the original C language.

Comment: @R Samuel: True the example given doesn't apply to C

Answer (score -2):

Because C allows one to do :

```
if (x) { // As opposed to java where you need to do if (x == something)
   // your code
}
```

As you can see above flexibility gives rise to ambiguity as others have shown.

Comment: You can write the same thing in Java if 'x' is Boolean, and Java requires the parentheses just like C codes.  Doesn't answer the question in any way.